# Is it possible to play Novation Launchkey Midi controller without computer

Tags: instruments

I am planning to buy Novation Launchkey midi controller. But I am wondering if I can play this keyboard just like other ordinary keyboard by just connected to power ? Is it mandatory that it to be connected with a drvice to play sound? Can it store midi waves and enable them to play while we are travelling? I really don't  want to do a lots of configuration and connection just for playing it. Would it work just like other keyboards?

Comment: By the way, there's no such thing as 'midi waves' - perhaps you mean 'audio samples'? or 'patches'?

Answer (score 4):

No, it has no sounds in it and it won't make any sounds on its own - it can only control another device (usually a computer) via MIDI - that other device is what makes the sounds.

This is typical of keyboards that are called 'controller' keyboards or MIDI 'controllers' - they can *only* control other devices.

Many normal keyboards with sounds can also be used *as* MIDI controllers, however. It sounds like a normal keyboard with sounds *and* MIDI may be what you need instead.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on topo morto's comment, you can connect a MIDI controller to a "sound module." Sound modules are made by lots of different companies with all sorts of different features and sound sets, but they are basically just a box that you plug a MIDI controller into that sends sounds out.

So a sound module can take the place of the computer.

Comment: Be careful - a lot of modern midi controllers do NOT have standard MIDI out and simply plugging a USB cable from a controller keyboard into a module usually does not work.  You need a computer or something else that acts as a host (? not sure if that's the right terminology) to get the USB talking to both devices.